# How to delete file from the server after auto upload

Tags: node.js, reactjs, filepond

When I select an image it automatically uploads which is what I want, and then using Node.js and Multer I rename the file to make it unique and save it to disk. However, once the upload is complete, the progress loader turns into a 'X' and the file can be deleted. When I click on that the image is removed from react but it remains on the server.

In React:

```
          <FilePond
            files={files}
            onupdatefiles={setFiles}
            allowMultiple={false}
            maxFiles={1}
            server="http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/update-avatar"
            name="image"
            labelIdle='Drag & Drop your files or <span class="filepond--label-action">Browse</span>'
          />
```

In Node.js

```
const MIME_TYPE_MAP = {
  "image/png": "png",
  "image/jpg": "jpg",
  "image/jpeg": "jpeg",
};

const fileUpload = multer({
  limits: 500000,
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, "uploads/images/");
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      const ext = MIME_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];
      console.log(file);
      cb(null, uuidv1() + "." + ext);
    },
  }),
  fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
    const isValid = !!MIME_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];
    let error = isValid ? null : new Error("Invalid mime type");
    cb(error, isValid);
  },
});
router:

router.post(
  "/update-avatar",
  fileUpload.single("image"),
  userController.updateAvatar
);
```

If I console.log 'file' I only get the below which doesn't help because I rename the file.

```
{
  fieldname: 'image',
  originalname: 'bob.png',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/png'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to create a `revert` api endpoint server side, where you manually clean-up by removing the previously uploaded file. You have to specify that link on your component :

```
<FilePond
      server={{
        process: {
          url: "/api/v1/users/update-avatar"
        },
        revert: {
          url: "/api/v1/users/revert-avatar",
        }
     }}
     // ...
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I work around this issue was by ussing its event "removefile", because in there you can then call your endpoint and remove the file as Ernest say..."manually".

How did you solve it at the end?

Vuejs... example

```
template...
    <file-pond ref="pond" name="filePondImages" @init="handleFilePondInit" @removefile="onDeleteImageCall" :files="innerImages" />

script...
  methods: {
    onDeleteImageCall(error, file){
       if(error){ ... }
    
       ... code here
    }
    ...
   }
```